# Call Java function from native function based on cached jobject and methodID fail

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

**Java source:**

```
public void onEventListener(final int eventID, final int arg1,
            final long arg2, final String message) 
{
     Log.d("TEST", "onEventListener() is called - eventID = "+eventID);
}
```

---

**JNI code:**

```
JavaVM* gJvm = NULL;

pid_t _vm_tid = -1;

JNIEnv * jEnv = NULL;

jclass native_cls_id = NULL;

jmethodID _onEventListenerID=NULL;

jobject m_nativeObj = NULL;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
        ....

    gJvm = vm;
    _vm_tid = gettid();
        ....
}
```

//Function

```
void NotifyFromNative(int eventID, int arg1, long arg2, char* message) {
    LOGD("Receive_Message_Callback is called - eventID = %d",eventID);

    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    pid_t tid = gettid();
    LOGD("Step 0");
    if (tid != _vm_tid) {

        jint ret = gJvm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        LOGD("Step 1 - tid != _vm_tid ret=%d",ret);

    } else {
        LOGD("Step 1 - tid == _vm_tid");
        gJvm->GetEnv((void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
    }
    LOGD("Step 2");

    jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF(message);
    LOGD("Step 3");

    env->CallVoidMethod(m_nativeObj, _onEventListenerID, eventID, arg1, arg2,
            jstr);
    LOGD("Step 4");
    env->DeleteLocalRef(jstr);

    if (tid != _vm_tid)
        gJvm->DetachCurrentThread();
}
```

---

//Initialize JNI function

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_NativeManager_initialize(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject obj) {

    LOG_UI("Native initialize is called");

    m_nativeObj = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);

    jclass cls = env->FindClass(classPathName);
    if (cls == NULL) {
        LOGE("Can't find class %s", classPathName);
        return 0;
    }

    native_cls_id = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(cls);
    _onEventListenerID = env->GetMethodID(native_cls_id, "onEventListener",
                "(IIJLjava/lang/String;)V");

    if (!_onEventListenerID)
        {
         LOGE("Can't find onEventListener Java method");
             return 0;
    }   
        char* message = "test";
    jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF(message);
        env->CallVoidMethod(m_nativeObj, _onEventListenerID, 1, 1, 1,
                jstr); //This call work well

    NotifyFromNative(0, 1, 1, "test"); //<= problem here

}
```

---

**Logcat message**

```
onEventListener() is called - eventID = 1 
Receive_Message_Callback is called - eventID = 0
Step 0
Step 1 - tid == _vm_tid
Step 2
Step 3 
W/dalvikvm(2160): Invalid indirect reference 0x576725d0 in decodeIndirectRef
E/dalvikvm(2160): VM aborting
A/libc(2160): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 2160 ()
```

**Question:**

Can anyone explain for me why calling NotifyFromNative(0, 1, 1, "test") has the problem although the global reference of objects are created. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Android JNI function can't use Long parameter. So, I break Long value into 2 Integer values and the code is working now.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old question I randomly stumbled upon it. But the current answer is just wrong. The issue lies here

```
void NotifyFromNative(int eventID, int arg1, long arg2, char* message) {
```

It should be

```
void NotifyFromNative(int eventID, int arg1, jlong arg2, char* message) {
```

Notice the jlong. long in java is 64bit. long in c/c++ is not guaranteed to be that size. jlong ensures a compatible type with long in java.